# goodness of fit for two histograms

Tags: goodness-of-fit, histogram

I have two histograms and I want to how good they match with each other. Are there any method available to test their goodness of fit ? Can anyone suggest some methods that can say how good they fit each other.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may check these two links http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/doing-a-chi-square-independence-test-in-mathematica and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5579/performing-a-chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test

Answer (score 1):

For visual comparisons you can just superimpose them on each other. Else, for more quantitative kind of approach try using a 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

`KolmogorovSmirnovTest[{list1,list2}]`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I was thinking of doing chi-square test. But I don't know how to do chi-square for a histogram.

Comment: your welcome. just search on the site and somebody might have done it.